# Converting TObjectList ancestor to generic collection in Delphi

Tags: delphi, list, generics, delphi-2009

I've got a class

```
TMyAwesomeList = class(TObjectList)
```

which holds

```
 TAwesomeItem = class(TPersistent)
```

where TAwesomeItem is pretty much an abstract class for

```
 TAwesomeItem1 = class(TAwesomeItem)
 TAwesomeItem2 = class(TAwesomeItem)
 TAwesomeItem3 = class(TAwesomeItem)
 TAwesomeItem3a = class(TAwesomeItem3)
```

and so on (about 30 subclasses where there are a few intermediate abstract classes) that accomplish some object relational modeling I implemented a year ago in anticipation of finally converting from Delphi 7 to 2009 (and soon XE2).

The code still works in Delphi 2009, but I want to do a

```
 for AwesomeItem3a in AwesomeList do
 begin     
    //something awesome
 end;
```

and I don't know how to go about restructuring the TMyAwesomeList (or adding several subclasses) to make this work.

Comment: Is the list homogenous, ie. all items are of the same concrete type? If so, you can just use `type TMyAwesomeList1 = TObjectList<TMyAwesomeItem1>; TMyAwesomeList2 = TObjectList<TMyAwesomeItem2>;` etc. Otherwise, you need to specify how you expect your `for ... in` loop to work.

Comment: There's not much in the original TAwesomeList, except 4 constructors which populate the list with the correct TAwesomeItem type and  overridden GetItem/SetItem methods that I can get rid of with generics.  Yeah, I think they can all be of the same type, originally I had programmed it without that in mind, but never used it that way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on your comments, it seems you can simply use `TObjectList` directly.

```
var
  MyAwesomeList1: TObjectList<TMyAwesomeItem1>;
  MyAwesomeItem1: TMyAwesomeItem1;
begin
  MyAwesomeList1 := TObjectList<TMyAwesomeItem1>.Create;
  try
    // populate the list...

    for MyAwesomeItem1 in MyAwesomeList1 do
      ...
  finally
    MyAwesomeList1.Free;
  end;
end;
```

... and same for `TMyAwesomeItem2`, etc.
If you prefer, you can also declare a type alias:

```
type
  TMyAwesomeList1 = TObjectList<TMyAwesomeItem1>;
  TMyAwesomeList2 = TObjectList<TMyAwesomeItem2>;
  // etc.
```

Comment: That's probably right, the only thing I need to do is replace the constructors I was using with the `// populate the list...`, I guess I just wished there was a magic way to do it, thanks!

Comment: Regarding the constructors, the situation has now changed: you have a separate list type for each item type. It might be possible to come up with a generic item constructor as a method of the list. Depends on your code.